# can't enable check_box_tag in haml rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I try to enable check_box in haml, I do the following:

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, true
```

but it doesn't appear with checked mark. My whole code for this form looks like this:

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => 'ratings_form' do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, true
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', id: "ratings_submit"
```

any advice will be helpful. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `form` belongs to `create` or `edit`?

Comment: no my form acts like a filter where I set values which I want to display. It belongs to index, to be clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by default it takes value as `1`

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", true
```

Comment: Yep, I tried this already, but it doesn't work

Comment: You want to check all the checkboxes generating in a loop?

Comment: 1 step. I try to enable all of them, because based on this movies will  be showed